# request en el callback de passport igual a null

Tags: nodejs, passport

bueno tal como lo dice el titulo al realizar un login con passport todo va bien hasta que llega la parte del callback.

como informacion importante estoy usando react para el frontend y quiero que al validar el usuario quiero establecer una session con "req.login()" pero resulta que req llega a la funcion con un valor null y no tengo idea por que.

**Aqui les dejo el codigo de la configuración de passport**

```js
const localStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const mysql = require('mysql');

var config=require('../database');
var conexionABaseDeDatos=mysql.createConnection(config);

module.exports= function(passport){

    passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
        done(null,user);
    });

    
    passport.deserializeUser(function(user, done) {
        console.log(user);
        let correo=user.correo;
  conexionABaseDeDatos.query("select * from users where correo = "+correo,function(err,rows){
            if (err) return done(null,err);

   done(null, rows[0]);
  });
    })






    passport.use(
        new localStrategy({
            usernameField: 'correo'
        },
        (email,password,done) =>{
            var buscarCorreo="SELECT * FROM users where correo = '"+email+"'";
            conexionABaseDeDatos.query(buscarCorreo,function(err,result){
                if(err) throw err;

                //si no existe el correo
                if (!result.length) return done(null,false);

                //si la contraseña es igual
                if(password==result[0].contrasenia){
                    return done(null,result);
                }else return done(null,false);
                
            })
        })
    );

}
```

**aqui el callback**

```js
router.post('/login',function(req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('local',(req,user,info)=>{
    console.log(req);
    console.log(user);
   // console.log(`req.session.passport: ${JSON.stringify(req.session.passport)}`)
    req.logIn(user,function(err){
      if(err) return next(err);
      console.log('Dentro del req.login() callback')
      console.log('User', user);

    })
    
  })(req, res, next);
});
```

como información adicional estoy usando react para el frontend por eso quiero hacer un res.json() para manejar los componentes que se muestran desde el front

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Según la documentación de passport http://www.passportjs.org/docs/authenticate/

el primer parámetro de la función passport authenticate local es err

```
passport.authenticate('local',(err,user,info)=>{ 
...
});
```

por ello cuando imprimes ese primer parámetro te aparece `NULL`, te está generando el `user` y no hay ningún error